# Amplify gets an appClientId from nowhere and now can't update the stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm developing an application using Amplify
Everything was doing fine, I have done some changes on my `dev` environment to include Social login, and it was working fine locally

Then when I tried to deploy using Amplify Console CD it was failing, after digging into it I found the solution [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/206) using a custom script for the `amplify simplepush`

Just to put this on context

After having everything working again, I was happy to push my changes to `staging`
So, I have changed my branch, checkout the `staging` environment and tried to push

And then I got stuck in an error raised saying that it can't find the AppClientID

> Resource Name: XXXXXXXXXXX (AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient)
>   Event Type: update
>   Reason: User pool client does not exist. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
>   URL: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/stacks/xxxxxxxxxxx

The URL goes to a **The page you are looking for does not exist.** page
The client Id, true, it doesn't exist, and I have no idea why it is trying to update it

So I looked at both
`amplify/#current-cloud-backend/amplify-meta.json`
and 
`amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json`

Both contain a line of code like this (on the auth->output section):

```
"AppClientID": "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

The `#current-cloud-backend` is supposed to come from the cloud, so I'm not supposed to touch it, but I have no idea how it did get that code, the `dev` appClient is not this code either.

So, I tried changing the code to (on the `amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json` file):
    "AppClientID": "MY-VALID-ID"

and then pushing again

But the error continues, and then the `amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json` was updated with the wrong id again

Any idea what might be causing it and how to fix it?